# Mac OSX 10.6.6 - Is it possible to allow access to a directory that is inside a directory you don't want to give access to

Tags: macos

Inside "MyDir/Library/Application Support/Games" is a directory I would like to allow all users to read.  I don't, however, want them to be able to read any other directory in MyDir.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a really good way to do this, because in order to get to that directory, other users will need to be able to get into MyDir, MyDir/Library, etc.  That said, there are a couple of ways to sort-of accomplish it:

1. You could set the permissions on MyDir, MyDir/Library, etc to allow traversal, but not reading.  Problems with this approach: other users won't be able to navigate to the folder normally, they'd have to use the Finder's Go to Folder option (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) and type in the path to it.  Also, although they wouldn't be able to see the contents of MyDir, MyDir/Library, etc, they would be able to access the files there if they new (/could guess) the names.  Since the contents of Libraries tend to be pretty predictable, this means they'd be able to get at MyDir/Library/Preferences, MyDir/Library/Keychains, etc unless you properly protected those as well.  Assuming you wanted to do this, here are the relevant setup commands (warning: these are not easily reversible, please think carefully before executing):

   ```
   chmod og= MyDir/* MyDir/Library/* MyDir/Library/Application\ Support/*
   chmod og=x MyDir MyDir/Library MyDir/Library/Application\ Support
   chmod og=rx MyDir/Library/Application\ Support/Games
   ```
2. You could actually put the contents somewhere more accessible, and make MyDir/Library/Application Support/Games a symlink to it.  Potential problems with this come from programs that don't follow symlinks (especially, installers that might replace it with an actual directory -- you'd have to clean up after that one by hand). Here's an example, using /Users/Shared/Games as the public location:

   ```
   mkdir /Users/Shared/Games
   ln -s /Users/Shared/Games MyDir/Library/Application\ Support/Games
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Here's a question about "Go to Folder."  If I make "MyDir/Library/Application Support/Games" inaccessible, but give the subfolder Read permission, can one get to that subfolder via "Go to Folder?"  I need to specify the subfolder in an applications preferences page, so I only need to point to it once.

Comment: p.s.  How do I put a line break in a post?

Comment: @Ted Trobaugh: Yes, Go to Folder can go "through" folders you don't have read access to, as long as you have x (search/traverse) access.  It occurs to me that you could probably also hand out aliases to the folder, although I haven't tested that option.  BTW, I don't think there's a way to put a line break in a comment.